# User authentication on server supporting both simple HTTP and Websocket

Tags: http, session, authentication, websocket

Users can connect to a server via simple HTTP or Websocket.

What happens to the Websocket session when HTTP Session expires ?
What happens to the HTTP Session when a Websocket session is closed ?

How is it possible to handle user authentication on a server supporting both protocols ?

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [Ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) is the document that defines the WebSockets protocol and it does't prescribe any particular way to authenticate a client:

> [**10.5. WebSocket Client Authentication**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-10.5)
>
> This protocol doesn't prescribe any particular way that servers can authenticate clients during the WebSocket handshake. The WebSocket server can use any client authentication mechanism available to a generic HTTP server, such as cookies, HTTP authentication, or TLS authentication.

While WebSockets and HTTP can benefit from the same infrastructure (proxies, filtering, authentication), bear in mind that HTTP and WebSockets are **different channels of communication** and it must be taken into account when designing an authentication mechanism: It is a common misconception that a user who is authenticated in the hosting web application is also authenticated in the socket stream.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, there's usually only one session cookie - the HTTP session.

Since WebSocket connections start as HTTP, it is often that the connection authenticates during the HTTP phase and only upgrades to WebSocket once the authentication was successful...

... this depends on the application's design, but it's often the case.

If the session is invalidated after the WebSocket connection was established, the connection will (often) remain open and authenticated for as long as it lasts (since most applications won't repeat the authentication stage after the connection was established).

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how your application handles it. As @Myst mentioned, there's usually only one session cookie - the HTTP session. Your server application can close websocket when that session is invalid, or remain it open till the next time a connection is made. Its just the matter of when you are checking sessions that are attached to the websocket: Only when connection is made? or when a message is received?